# ionChange is being called on two objects, but only being declared on one of them

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have two objects using the samge ngModel.

```
<ion-item [hidden]="customerListEnabled">
  <ion-label stacked>Customer Name or Destination</ion-label>
  <ion-input ng-required='!customerListEnabled' type="text" name="patient-name" maxlength="30" [(ngModel)]='visit.patientName'></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item [hidden]="!customerListEnabled">
  <ion-label stacked>Customer Name or Destination</ion-label>
  <ion-select ng-required='customerListEnabled' #customer (ionChange)="changeCustomer(customer.value)" name='patient-name' [(ngModel)]='visit.patientName'>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of patients" value="{{item.patient_name}}">{{item.patient_name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

There are conditions that will show one or the other, but never both at the same time. As you can see, they both have the same [(ngModel)]. For some reason, in the input one the event `changeCustomer()` is being called, even though it is only specified in the select. I know they both have the same name, so I tried changing them to unique names for both and I still had the same problem. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` instead of `hidden`, because `hidden` will just hide the dom and does not remove it completely from the view.

```
<ion-item *ngIf="!customerListEnabled">
  <ion-label stacked>Customer Name or Destination</ion-label>
  <ion-input ng-required='!customerListEnabled' type="text" name="patient-name" maxlength="30" [(ngModel)]='visit.patientName'></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item *ngIf="customerListEnabled">
  <ion-label stacked>Customer Name or Destination</ion-label>
  <ion-select ng-required='customerListEnabled' #customer (ionChange)="changeCustomer(customer.value)" name='patient-name' [(ngModel)]='visit.patientName'>
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of patients" value="{{item.patient_name}}">{{item.patient_name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```